# How to get name of downloading file (PHP)

Tags: php, file, download, get

How I can get downloading file with its original name?
URL doesn't have name.

URL's format: `http://someurl/?RANDOMSYMBOLS`

URL returns named file, but all of known me PHP's methods drop to server RENAMED file, with MY name, NOT original.

I using `file_put_contents("Tmpfile.zip", fopen("http://someurl/?RANDOMSYMBOLS", 'r'))`, but it drops file as `"Tmpfile.zip"`, not with original name (name of file which common user with common browser gets when navigate to url).

I want to know name of that file and drop with that. No problem when URL has format `"example.com/?filename"`, but no, it doesn't contain name.

Comment: what do you mean exactly , i don't got it

Comment: Okay. I using file_put_contents("Tmpfile.zip", fopen("http://someurl/?RANDOMSYMBOLS", 'r')) But it drops file as "Tmpfile.zip", not with original name (name of file which common user with common browser gets when navigate to url). I want to know name of that file and drop with that. No problem when URL has format "example.com/?filename", but no, it doesn't contain name.

Comment: What you can try to do is to use cURL on example.com?RANDOM and then get the final URL by the follow_location option. Of course this assumes that the script redirects to the file. If it simple outputs the file from that URL then it won't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to read http response headers , http headers contains fileName , size... etc
and its necessary to use curl because fopen dont show you headers

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/file.zip");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

// Then, after your curl_exec call:
$header_size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
$header = substr($response, 0, $header_size);
$body = substr($response, $header_size);
```

print $header to see headers list with

```
var_dump($header);
```

and $body contains file data